# Select lines starting with specific numbers

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep, ps

I have to show the `PID`, `PPID` and `STATUS` of the procceses on the system, but only the ones which `PID` starts with numbers in the range 5-8. So i tried something like this...

```
ps xao pid,ppid,s | grep ' 5'
```

But then I don’t know how to do it for the range, I can make it work for one number, but not for all of them.

Answer (score 4):

```
ps xao pid,ppid,s | grep '^ *[5-8]'
```

If the PID is five digits, you don't have a space at the beginning of the line, hence the `' *'` part after grep. `'^'^` only searches at the beginning (thereby not selecting PPID  is starting with 5,6,7,80 and. `'[5-8]'` handles the range of numbers you wanted (could also do `'[5678]'`)

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
ps xao pid,ppid,s | grep '^ *[5-8]'
```

- `^` means: start of line (or string)
- `*` is a quantifier (for preceding character) : zero or N
- `[]` is the meta-character to indicate a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) range, here 5 to 8